# How to grab data from an external URL

Tags: php

I have an application where a url will be generated from website #1, after a user signs up.

(i.e. user will get their own url: http://www.example.com/?affid=12345)

I need to grab the numbers in the above url by using PHP, but I don't understand how this would work.  How can I grab the actual numbers from the url above using PHP?

I should also mention that the website where I will generating PHP code is not on the same server as the URL above.

Comment: Do you mean get affid and affid is in the url? bit unclear. If you do you would use $_GET like: `$affid = $_GET['affid'];`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for that:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/?affid=12345';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $vars);
echo $vars['affid']; // outputs 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number i.e 12345 in this URL http://www.example.com/?affid=12345, use [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)  which will give you an associative array. you can use $_GET and $_REQUEST throught the application, while using `$_GET` OR `$_REQUEST` you must clean before using in your code.

```
echo $_GET['affid'];
```

OR

```
echo $_REQUEST['affid'];
```

Comment: That works only if 'http://www.example.com/?affid=12345' is the current url. I think thatRob's searching to analyze a string url as a url recorded in his database (example : website's user)

Comment: @AlexandreT agreed, but question is not very clear, so I answered in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_url](http://cct.me.ntut.edu.tw/ccteducation/chchting/aiahtm/computer/phphelp/function.parse-url.php.htm) function to extract the query

```
<?php
     $url   = 'http://www.example.com/?affid=12345';
     $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
     echo $parsed_url['query'];
     //print : affid=12345
?>
```

After that, you can parse the result with [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function

```
<?php
    parse_str($parsed_url['query'],$result);
    var_dump($result);
    //print  array(1) { ["affid"]=> string(5) "12345" }
    echo $values[0]
    //print 12345
?>
```